# Were ancient Hindu polytheists?

Tags: puranas, dharma, rig-veda, worship, agamas

Only looking for Ancient Shastras and Agamic or Tantra or Rig Vedaic based on answers. Pre-Vedic based question.

For Ancient History of Sanatana Dharma Students and Scholars.

1.Where Hindu and can Hindu be  accepted also as polytheist?
Is mandatory to only believe in 1 God?

Rig Vedic Times there were Visvedevas and people worshipped many Gods.
It is that true or they had a ParamIshwara?

Nowadays can be possible too to worship more Devas or Gods according to Sanatana Dharmo Gyaan?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because belongs on History SE

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118399/discussion-between-hindustudent-thewhitehindu-and-mr-green).